# Can I to use 2 adsl lines simultaneously?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, adsl, ics

I've got a ADSL Router linked to a hub/switch, where are linked all PCs in my house. In my neighborhood I can get the line speed only to max of 600 kbps. I was thinking about contract another 600 kbps ADSL line and link in my router, but I don't know if in the end I will get 1200 kpbs (1.2 mbps).

Another good reason is that if one line drops due some problem, I will be on-line, even in half of the full speed.

It's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this before with 2 4MB ADSL lines, however have never been able to get them to bond. [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.com/) is a BSD based firewall router that has built in support for multiple ADSL lines in a load balanced environment.

There is also various dual ADSL routers available. These will provide you similar solutions. [Molly](https://superuser.com/questions/50920/can-i-to-use-2-adsl-lines-simultaneously/50926#50926) already provided a link to one that can. I have not been able to source these locally in ZA but know they should be available in the States with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll need a dual ADSL router for bonding the two connections.

Zyxel's **[P-663H-51](http://www.zyxel.com/web/product_family_detail.php?PC1indexflag=20040812093058&display=6241&CategoryGroupNo=7E42490D-4723-431D-B284-F66F17AC2CD8)** has two ADSL2/2+ WAN ports. With the ATM-based multi-paired bonding feature, the two ports can be grouped into a logical link boasting the bandwidth twice as fast.

[image]

Comment: not true; he could build a dual-homed system (gateway with two NICs), connect each NIC to a separate ADSL modem, and do the bonding with OpenBSD, Linux, or whatever OS he wants.