# Connect 1 PC to 2 ADSL Lines and Get Twice Bandwidth

Tags: networking, router, adsl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I to use 2 adsl lines simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/50920/can-i-to-use-2-adsl-lines-simultaneously)

I have subscribed to 2 ADSL lines. I wanna know is it possible to connect both of them to a single PC and get double the bandwidth? I have 2 routers but each of them can only connect to just one line. Can I get an extra network adapter and connect it to one of the routers? Is it possible and if so, what is the minimum requirement to achieve this?